# Expression Monad

Tags: haskell, expression, monads, option-type

I got the task:

```
data Exp = Con Int | Sum Exp Exp | Division Exp Exp
```

Write the function evalM, which evaluate the Expression Exp and put it in an Maybe.
You are not allowed to use the constructor Just and you have to solve it with DO or >>=.

So My Code is:

```
evalM1 :: Exp -> Int
evalM1 e = evalM2 e where
           evalM2 :: Exp -> Int
           evalM2 (Con i) = (i)
           evalM2 (Sum e1 e2) = (evalM2 e1)+(evalM2 e2)
           evalM2 (Division e1 e2) = div (evalM2 e1) (evalM2 e2)

evalM :: Exp -> Maybe Int
evalM e = do
          return (evalM1 e)

-- Second try
evalM e = do
          y <- Just (evalM1 e)
          return y
```

So my Question is why does the first evalM works without Just and the Second evalM works only if i use Just (y <- Just..) ?

And maybe someone can write me the solution with >>=.

Thank you very much!

Solution:

```
evalM :: Exp -> Maybe Int
evalM (Con i) = return i 
evalM (Neg x) = evalM x >>= \v -> return (-v)
evalM (Sum e1 e2) = evalM e1 >>= \a -> evalM e2 >>= \b -> (return (a+b))
evalM (Division e1 e2) = evalM e1 >>= \a -> evalM e2 >>= (\b -> guard(b/=0) >> (return (div a b)))

> *Test> evalM (Division (Con 1) (Division (Con 0) (Con 1))) ~> Nothing
> *Test> evalM (Division (Con 1) (Sum (Con 2) (Neg (Con 2)))) ~> Nothing
```

Comment: I don't understand the requirement `You are not allowed to use the constructor Just`. I don't see how to do it without using `Just` - unless of course we're allowed to use `return` (or `pure`) which in the context of the `Maybe` type are just synonyms...

Comment: btw your code confuses me a little, I do not know why you are evaluating `Con i` as `-i` rather than the natural `i`. And what happens in the division case if the second expression evaluates to zero? I'm pretty sure that case is why you are asked to return a `Maybe Int` rather than just an `Int`

Comment: @RobinZigmond Not exactly synonyms. `return` and `pure` are functions, whereas `Just` is a constructor, meaning you can use it in a pattern match. I think the idea of the constraint is to forbid you from pattern-matching on `Just`, while still allowing you to build a `Just` value, by way of `pure`.

Comment: @amalloy - fair enough, that makes sense

Comment: Hint: `evalM :: Monad m => Exp -> m Int` with `evalM = pure . evalM1` would work for *any* monad, `Maybe` included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint.

First, you have to understand why the result of the evaluation is a `Maybe Int` instead of a simpler `Int`. Intuitively, `Maybe Int` contains all the possible values for `Int`, plus a special one (`Nothing`). What is the additional value for?

Likely, that additional value is to be used to capture division by zero errors. That is, if we need to divide by zero in our expression, we should return `Nothing` instead of causing a runtime error.

Your `evalM1` function ignores this fact, and simply tries to divide numbers, returning a simple `Int`. This `Int` return type is a half lie, though, since division by zero is not really handled. Dividing by zero there causes a runtime error instead of a nicer special value `Nothing`.

Note that we can't simply define `evalM :: Exp -> Maybe Int` wrapping `evalM1`. Code like

```
evalM e = return (evalM1 e)
```

will type, but will not handle division by zero as a special case.

I'd suggest you ignore `evalM1` and instead build `evalM` from scratch. You can follow a similar recursion pattern:

```
evalM :: Exp -> Maybe Int
evalM (Con i) = ...
evalM (Sum e1 e2) = ...
evalM (Division e1 e2) = ...
```

For the sum case: note that we can't write recursion calls `evalM e1 + evalM e2` since we can't `+` two `Maybe Int` since they are not numbers. That is however not a real issue. We can instead perform the two calls inside a `do` block, fetching their results (if any, recall they could return `Nothing`), and then finally `+` and `return` the sum.

Division is similar, but remember to check for `0`.

As a last note, let me address your "question as asked". Why does `x <- Just number` only works with `Just`. Well, that's because we are working inside the `Maybe` monad here, so every expression following `<-` must have a type of the form `Maybe something`. So we can't write `x <- (42 :: Int)`. Without `Just` we could write instead `let x = (42 :: Int)` inside the `do` block, but you won't need that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added my solution and it works perfect.

Comment: @kingingo - well done, but I don't think the solution you've posted is quite right yet. (Although it's nearly there.) There are ways for `Division e1 e2` to give a division by zero error other than when `e2` is `Con 0`, which is the only case you've handled.

Comment: @kingingo You're almost there. Try dividing by zero, your solution still triggers an error instead of returning `Nothing`. After you get both `a` and `b`, you need to check if `b == 0` before performing the division. You could use `if b==0 then .. else ..`

Comment: But I did it already with pattern matching "evalM (Division e1 (Con 0)) = Nothing" or is it false?

Comment: What happens if you try, for example, `evalM $ Division (Con 1) $ Sum (Con 2) (Con (-2))`?

Comment: @kingingo division by zero does not mean division by literal zero, consider e.g. `1/(0/1)`, which is not handled by your program, but should be. Robin also suggests `1/(2+(-2))`, which should also be handled. You should check the semantic result of an expression against 0, not its syntax.

Comment: So I updated my solutions again and added an guard :). I also tested it. Btw Thank you very much guys for your help